# Flex Box and Media Query

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

Do you still need media queries to make website responsive when you have already used flex box? Are there any instances where media queries give us better control?

Comment: where is the code? we cant help without the code. also this question is too opionated/ verbose

Comment: flex not working well sometimes. you should use always media queries website responsive

Comment: if u want to style responsive for particular device u need media queries because always flex won't work and flex its work for till tab device but after that, for a mobile device, we need to use the media queries ( mobile screen).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a lot of things where you would still use media-queries. 
You would probably want to switch from **flex-basis: 200px;** to a more flexible **flex-basis: 50%;** width on mobiles.

A combination of both is probably best. 
If you are working with percentages and wan't a different column count on smaller devices there is imho no way around media queries.

Comment: same thing happens when you use flex-layout in angular? that is, if you use flex-layout, wouldn't it be considered bad practice to use media queries at some point? I want the height of a container to be different at different breakpoints (xs, sm, md, ...) but I can't find a way to do that directly with the flex-layout directives. Is there a way to do it? would it be wrong if I do it using media queries?

Comment: Using media queries is imho not bad practice when using flex-layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Flex-box** and **Grid Layout**, along with Multi-column layout are responsive by default. These specifications were written in a world where responsive design and supporting multiple devices was already a thing. This means that they include a lot of common sense functionality, which enables responsive design without us needing to do much.

If we want to change the size or proportions of some columns, we have to add a break-point using a Media Query and redefine them. We have no other options when working in percentages, as they will always be the same percentage of the container they are in, whether that container is wide or narrow.

Comment: same thing happens when you use flex-layout in angular? that is, if you use flex-layout, wouldn't it be considered bad practice to use media queries at some point? I want the height of a container to be different at different breakpoints (xs, sm, md, ...) but I can't find a way to do that directly with the flex-layout directives. Is there a way to do it? would it be wrong if I do it using media queries?

Answer (score 0):

`FlexBox` is one thing.
`Responsive Web Desing (RWD)` is something different.

**FlexBox is a native CSS set of properties** allowing you to apply some specific layout-related styles to your parent and child elements.

**RWD is an approach of adjusting the site to fit every screen size.** In order to achieve this, you use @MediaQueries.
Flexbox is not a replacement for mediaQueries. Magic happens when you use them together.
Imagine a situation where you want to replace an img scr in the "background" css property when user's screen size goes below 768px. How would You do that with Flexbox but without @Media rules ? 
MediaQueries are really powerful and give you a lot of possibilities to control different layouts on your site based on the screen width.

Comment: same thing happens when you use flex-layout in angular? that is, if you use flex-layout, wouldn't it be considered bad practice to use media queries at some point? I want the height of a container to be different at different breakpoints (xs, sm, md, ...) but I can't find a way to do that directly with the flex-layout directives. Is there a way to do it? would it be wrong if I do it using media queries?

Comment: Using media queries is a must in most cases to achieve fully responsive website. You can use it with every framework. Media queries is a CSS feature not Angular/React/Vue related thing. It's definately not a bad practice to have 3/4 breakpoints to adjust the styling of Your page. You can call it a bad practice when You have way too much breakpoints :)

Comment: okay. What it would be is to reuse the same flex-layout breakpoints. Example: xs = max-width: 599px, then I want that when the screen has a maximum width of 599px a container has a height of for example 300px; then in the CSS I would do a mean querie for max: width: 599px and put height: 300px.